# Adding two pandas Series while keeping (non-numeric) values at non-matching indices

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following two `pandas.Series` objects:

```
>>> s1 = Series([1, True, 3, 5], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'])
>>> s2 = Series([100, 300, 'foo', 500], index=['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> s1
a       1
b    True
c       3
e       5
dtype: object
>>> s2
a    100
c    300
d    foo
e    500
dtype: object
```

I would like to calculate the sum `s1+s2` where elements at non-matching indices should simply be "inherited" from `s1` or `s2` without change. So the result should look like this:

```
>>> Series([101, True, 303, 'foo', 505], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
a     101
b    True
c     303
d     foo
e     505
dtype: object
```

The naive approach does not work because it introduces `NaN` at the non-matching indices:

```
>>> s1 + s2
a    101
b    NaN
c    303
d    NaN
e    505
dtype: object
```

There are similar questions on StackOverflow that suggest solutions along the lines of `s1.add(s2, fill_value=0)`, but this doesn't work in my case because not all values are numeric, so `fill_value` is of no use. Is there an option which tells pandas to simply fill in the missing values from whichever Series they are present in?

It seems like such an obvious thing that I must surely be missing something, but I've been scouring both the documentation and StackOverflow and haven't found any answers. Many thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It's a joy to see a insightful and well-researched first question, for a change!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way I think would be to use [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
>>> s1 = pd.Series([1, True, 3, 5], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'e'])
>>> s2 = pd.Series([100, 300, 'foo', 500], index=['a', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
>>> (s1+s2).combine_first(s1).combine_first(s2)
a     101
b    True
c     303
d     foo
e     505
dtype: object
```

But to be honest, `Series` with varying type like this don't seem to come up for me often.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works nicely! I agree that the question may look a bit obscure at first, but it came up in the context of a DataFrame containing mostly numerical data plus a few extra non-numerical columns where I needed to subtract a fixed array from the numerical values in each row. I ended up using `df.apply(..., axis=1)` to subtract the fixed array from the rows but didn't manage to retain the non-numerical values in the extra columns. I may actually post that as a separate question to see if there is a better solution, but your answer makes it work for now. Thanks again!